# Asp.net Viewstate not saving a control's style

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have read that the viewstate in asp.net stores the values of **control properties** across postbacks.
Lets say I have a page that has a textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fldFileId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then on the client side via javascript, I get a reference to the element , and then set the border style thusly

```
refToTextBox.style["border-style"] = "dashed";
```

Upon postback, the border style has dissapeared and the textbox reverts to its original look. But glancing at the properties for an asp:TextBox in VS2010 there *is* a 'BorderStyle' property for it. 
Is there a reason why this attribute does not get saved in the view state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a value client-side does not update ViewState. You have to set the style server-side for ViewState to store it. Alternatively, you could:

1. Re-run your JavaScript after postback.
2. Store the styling in a cookie and use JavaScript to restore the style.
3. <strike>Find a JavaScript library to modify ViewState on the client-side</strike> (not recommended).

Comment: Because the value is posted to server-side. Check the `Request.Form` object in your code-behind (`Request.Form(MyTextBox.UniqueID)`) to see the value.

Comment: Thanks, I realised this a few minutes after posting that comment, and decided to delete it. For the record the comment was: "So why does the value that I enter in the textbox persist after postback".