# Any ASP.NET controls that can hold a line-through style in the ViewState?

Tags: asp.net

I am not familiar with alot of the controls in ASP.NET

I have a page where the user can cross out (text-decoration:line-through) text using a javascript function when the text is clicked on.

My question is, are there any ASP.NET controls that can hold the line-through style in ViewState?

The goal is to keep all the crossing out on the same text when the page is reloaded.

Cheers.

Comment: no. there aren't any. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9712840/17447